# How to retrieve VIP ghost shell in Destiny: The Taken King?

Tags: destiny

I am eligible for the VIP rewards in TTK, and although I have not purchased it yet, I found that I can still get the items from the "panels" in the tower. So far I have my Sparrow, Emblem, and Shader, but I can't figure out where to get the final item, the ghost shell. Does anybody know where I would find it?

Comment: There is no VIP ghost shell, just the shader, sparrow and emblem. The collector's edition had a "frontier shell", but it isn't related to the VIP year 1 rewards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you are supposed to receive all of your VIP items from a quest that you get after purchasing TTK. The fact that some are available via the terminals is a bug.

The quest you get takes you to most or all of the vendors in the tower, and most give you an item - the Sparrow from Holiday, the Shader from Eva Levante, etc. IIRC the Speaker gives you the ghost.

In fact, if/when you do purchase TTK and do the quest, you won't be able to proceed with the quest when they try to give you one of the items you got from the terminals since you can only have one at a time. You'll need to delete them from your inventory in order to finish the quest.

Comment: can confirm, the speaker gives you the ghost.

Answer (score 1):

if you picked up the items before TTK came out on the 15th of September, then you wont be able able to pick them up as you will not get the quest. the quest will let you pick up the shader, the sparrow and the ghost shell. you would also have gotten an engram which will turn into a year 1 PlayStation exclusive exotic. if you picked up any of these items before TTK then you will have missed out.